# PHP - How to retrieve data from $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, forms, http-post

I have a form on one page and that submits to an other page. When trying to retrieve the data with $_post, it fails. var_dump however shows the form entries.
I couldn't find any answers for my problem.
I tried changing the php.ini file like some users advised or adding a .htaccess with some rewrite rules. So I think my problem is in my code? 
If used the php code on the same page it however works. But I want the result on another page.

*My HTML:*

```html
<div id="invoerForm">
 <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
  Serienummer: <br>
  <input type="Text" name="Serienummer"><br>
  Status: <br>
  <input type="Text" name="Status"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Voeg toe">
 </form>
 
</div>
```

*My $_POST:*

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Serienummer: <? echo $_POST['Serienummer'] ?></p>
<p>Status: <? echo $_POST["Status"]; ?></p>
<p><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

*var_dump*

array(2) { ["Serienummer"]=> string(1) "q" ["Status"]=> string(1) "q" }

*Result of $_POST*

Serienummer:

Status:

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try after changin <? to <?php

Comment: Oh wow that was really stupid that I didn't see that -.-

Comment: For `<?` to work in php you need to allow it in the php.ini file, I think it's called shorthand or something.

Comment: Don't forget to filter your output, your code is now vulnerable to `XSS` attacks. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting and http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: It's called `short_open_tag`, is by default disabled and shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write `php`

change `<?` to `<?php`

```
<p>Serienummer: <?php echo $_POST['Serienummer'] ?></p>
<p>Status: <?php echo $_POST["Status"]; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, in PHP's settings, [short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled.

This allows you to write PHP code with `<??>`

Without it, you have to write `<?php ?>`

Since PHP 5.4.0, `short_open_tags` is always available.